# Getting 1 Value to 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Good day.
I need to output look like this, is it possible this output.
[image: My Output]

**I have my script:**
myoutput is this
[image: my output]

```
SELECT q_type,q_title,qcategory_question 
FROM `survey_question` as sq LEFT JOIN 
          (SELECT id,qid,qcategory_question 
           FROM survey_category_question
          ) scq ON sq.id = scq.qid
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what does your output currently look like?

Comment: Yes, handle this presentation in your PHP code.  Nothing wrong with your current query per se.

Comment: my script output will 3times of 1. what was your dining experience?, 1. what was your dining experience? , 1. what was your dining experience?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ah.. thank you for your suggestion.. how should do it in php?

Comment: Why give -1 for my question? is that duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine.  You should handle the formatting in the application.  Now, I am going to make a different suggestion, which is to bring all the categories on a single row using `group by`:

```
SELECT sq.q_type, sq.q_title, GROUP_CONCAT(scq.qcategory_question)
FROM survey_question sq LEFT JOIN 
     survey_category_question scq
     ON sq.id = scq.qid
GROUP BY sq.q_type, sq.q_title;
```

Notes:

- Qualify all column names in the query, especially when you have more than one table reference.
- The subquery is unnecessary and probably detrimental in MySQL (most databases would ignore it, but MySQL may materialize it).
- The resulting categories will be in a comma-delimited list for output.

Answer (score 0):

Although i will not suggest you to do this in query as you could do that in php easily, you can try this..

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT q_type, CASE 
    WHEN A.mxnum = AA.num
        THEN q_title
    ELSE ' '
    END AS q_title, qcategory_question
FROM (
SELECT q_type, q_title, qcategory_question, (@row_number: = @row_number + 1) 
       AS num FROM `survey_question` AS sq
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id, qid, qcategory_question
    FROM survey_category_question
    ) AA
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT q_title, max(num) AS mxnum
    FROM (
        SELECT q_type, q_title, qcategory_question, (@row_number: = @row_number + 1) AS num
        FROM `survey_question` AS sq
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT id, qid, qcategory_question
            FROM survey_category_question
            ) scq
            ON sq.id = scq.qid
        )
    GROUP BY q_title
    ) A
    ON num = mxnum
);
```

hope this helps...